# Flink SQL automatically uploads Avro schema

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am facing some issues using Flink SQL automatically uploading a schema rather than using the one I have already uploaded. Here is my scenario:

I have a Kafka topic "input", which I want to be consumed by Flink, transforming the data and sending the output to another Kafka topic "output". I have defined Avro schemas for both the input and output topics and uploaded those to the schema registry using `curl`. Very simple, just a PoC.

So the input part goes fine, there it doesn't try to upload a schema itself, it just reads the data from the topic. However, when it then tries to write data to the output topic it uploads a schema that it has generated itself. My own schema which I have uploaded is as follows:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "OutputEvent",
  "namespace": "com.example",
  "doc": "Avro schema for a transformed PoC event",
  "version": 1,
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "category_type",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "Type of expense category"
    },
    {
      "name": "user_id",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "UUID uniquely identifying a user"
    },
    {
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "long",
      "doc": "The total amount spent in cents"
    },
    {
      "name": "time_window",
      "type": "long",
      "doc": "The window of this aggregate"
    }
  ]
}
```

But Flink tries to upload this schema to the registry which it then complains is incompatible:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "record",
  "namespace": "org.apache.flink.avro.generated",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "category_type",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "user_id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "time_window",
      "type": "long"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my output table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE aggregate
(
    category_type           STRING NOT NULL,
    user_id                 STRING NOT NULL,
    amount                  BIGINT NOT NULL,
    time_window             BIGINT NOT NULL
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'output',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9093',
    'properties.auto.register.schemas' = 'false',
    'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
    'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = 'http://localhost:8082',
    'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.subject' = 'output-value'
);
```

The property `"auto.register.schemas"` property was an experiment, unfortunately, it gets ignored.

Does anyone have any idea how I can prevent Flink SQL from uploading its own generated schema?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I found [out this](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/flink/reference/serialization.html#flink-sql-types-to-avro-types):

> For the record type:
>
> - name: `org.apache.flink.avro.generated.record`

It seems there's no way around it, I had to register my schema with that name to make it work:

```json
"name": "record",
"namespace": "org.apache.flink.avro.generated",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are on the right track, but it's not `properties.auto.register.schemas` but `value.avro-confluent.properties.auto.register.schemas`.

Next to that, you would also need to set `value.avro-confluent.properties.use.latest.version=true`

Comment: Cool, thanks, will try that later tonight. Would you happen to know where this is documented? I was scouring through the documentation as well as the source code but was unable to locate this property.

Comment: I'm not sure it's documented properly. If you're willing to open a PR for it, I can review and merge it :)

Comment: Hi Martijn, sorry for taking a bit of time to test this but I just got round to testing it but also with these properties set I still get the same exception. Using Flink 1.17.1 btw.